# Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Cannot open database

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c sqlcmd -S (localdb)\v11.0 -d Adv
entureWorksDW2008R2
```

I am getting the following error :

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Cannot open
>   database "A dventureWorksDW2008R2" requested by the login. The login
>   failed.

I am using active directory credentials... not using any special credentials; How to make the above command work for AD user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server is in no way connected to Active Directory.  Only users configured in SQL Server can log into SQL Server.  You will have to add the user to SQL Server.

Comment: For database credentials, I am not giving any credentials, usually sa/password ... But I am not giving any credentials to connect to the db. That is what I mean... :)

Comment: I am using windows authentication to connect to the DB

Comment: It seems you could follow up on the commenteres question. Please consider doing so, even if it's been a while.